# Clueless about this error: wrong sign in 'by' argument

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, rollapply

I have the following dataset:

```
 >k1[1:10,]
       id  web_name first_name second_name   position     date team1 team2 game_week points home_away team_scored team_conceded minutes goals assists
    1   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 17/08/13   ARS   AVL         1      0         H           1             3       0     0       0
    2   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 24/08/13   ARS   FUL         2      0         A           3             1       0     0       0
    3   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 01/09/13   ARS   TOT         3      0         H           1             0       0     0       0
    4   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 14/09/13   ARS   SUN         4      0         A           3             1       0     0       0
    5   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 22/09/13   ARS   STK         5      0         H           3             1       0     0       0
    6   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 28/09/13   ARS   SWA         6      0         A           2             1       0     0       0
    7   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 06/10/13   ARS   WBA         7      0         A           1             1       0     0       0
    8   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 19/10/13   ARS   NOR         8      0         H           4             1       0     0       0
    9   1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 26/10/13   ARS   CRY         9      0         A           2             0       0     0       0
    10  1 Fabianski     Lukasz   Fabianski Goalkeeper 02/11/13   ARS   LIV        10      0         H           2             0       0     0       0
```

When I run the code:

```
 > k2<- as.data.frame(k1 %>% group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(min1 = lag(minutes, default=NA)) %>%
 mutate(min3 = rollapply(min1,width=3,mean, align= "right", fill=NA)))
```

I receive the error:

```
Error: wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

However grouping by team1 via this code just works fine:

```
> k2<- as.data.frame(k1 %>% group_by(team1) %>%
   mutate(min1 = lag(minutes, default=NA)) %>%
   mutate(min3 = rollapply(min1,width=3,mean, align= "right", fill=NA)))
```

Pretty clueless why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason the second call is different in the `default` and `fill` parameters? Both are 0 in your non working attempt, and `NA` in your second

Comment: @erasmortg both are NA, I was just on a trial-and-error and pasted the wrong fragment. Edited.

Comment: Can you show some of your actual data via `head(dput())`? I can't seem to be able to reproduce your problem. Also, I don't think you need to wrap your calls in `as.data.frame()`, it will remove the grouping

Comment: There's no reason not to work with THIS dataset as you have one "id" and one "team" (1 and ARS). However, if you use a bigger dataset, then there's only one reason that it works with the "team1" grouping and not with "id". Probably there's an "id" (player id) in some team that has less than 3 rows. So the roallapply with width = 3 creates a problem. I guess there's no team with less than 3 rows, so it works fine. Hope I helped.

Comment: Yeah, you are right @AntoniosK , the dataset is actually quite big. And there are players (each with a unique id) who have less than 3 rows. Following change in the code helped me: 

    k2<- as.data.frame(k1 %>% group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(min1 = lag(minutes, default=NA)) %>%
    mutate(min3 = rollapply(min1,width=3,mean, align= "right", fill=NA,partial=TRUE)))

Answer (score 0):

It can have different reasons, But simply it can happen if you pass a **NULL dataframe** to rollapply function

Also consider the using of zoo() as

```
rollapply(Zoo(min1),width=3,mean, align= "right", fill=NA)
```