# Evaluate rolling mean by group when groups have insufficient observations

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, rollapply

I am trying to calculate a bunch of rolling means for a dataset -

```
     date name px_last 
2012-12-04   A  6.81  
2012-12-05   A  4.28  
2012-12-06   A  4.32
2012-12-04   A  6.89  
2012-12-05   A  7.24    
2012-12-04   B  6.81  
2012-12-05   B  9.38  
2012-12-06   B  3.62
2012-12-04   C  3.85  
2012-12-05   C  4.23  
2012-12-06   C  7.32
2012-12-04   C  2.84  
2012-12-05   C  8.38
```

The is the code I am using -

```
vec = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
for(i in c(1:length(vec))){
  varname = paste0("ma", vec[i])
  df = df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(!!varname := rollapplyr(px_last, vec[i], mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = "NA"))
}
```

The error I get from the third iteration is -

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: wrong sign in 'by' argument.
```

From this post - [Clueless about this error: wrong sign in 'by' argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896113/clueless-about-this-error-wrong-sign-in-by-argument) - I understand that is because some groups have insufficient rows; in this example, group with `name = B`

How do I got about calculating the means without deleting the groups with insufficient observations? I would like NAs preferably in places where the mean cannot be calculated due to insufficient observations.

Comment: What is `memb_hist` in `memb_hist %>% group_by() ...`?

Comment: @ANG, it is the name of the dataframe. Edited it now. Sorry!

Comment: @phil_t can you please paste what the df looks like

Comment: @Taran, added sample df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@phil_t So the issue is that the `rollapply` is attempting to apply the `mean` in a `right-aligned` fashion. When this is attempted on a window of size 4 on group `B`, which only has 3 values it correctly fails.

So you will need to "regularize" the DF to have the required number of rows for each group.

```
library(plyr)
> df <- ddply(df, 'name', function(x) {
                 rbind.fill(x, data.frame(name = rep(unique(x$name), each = max(vec) - nrow(x))))
              })

> df
  date name px_last
  2012-12-04    A    6.81
  2012-12-05    A    4.28
  2012-12-06    A    4.32
  2012-12-04    A    6.89
  2012-12-05    A    7.24
  2012-12-04    B    6.81
  2012-12-05    B    9.38
  2012-12-06    B    3.62
  <NA>    B      NA
  <NA>    B      NA
  2012-12-04    C    3.85
  2012-12-05    C    4.23
  2012-12-06    C    7.32
  2012-12-04    C    2.84
  2012-12-05    C    8.38

> for(i in c(1:length(vec))){
    varname = paste0("ma", vec[i])
    df = df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(!!varname := rollapplyr(px_last, vec[i], mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = "NA"))
  }
```

That should help.

Comment: The development version of zoo can handle series that are shorter than the width which would avoid the need for padding.  `devtools::install_github("rforge/zoo/pkg/zoo")` to install.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck thats pretty great. Has this been implemented in rollapply?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was referring to.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I installed the development version but the problem still occurs intermittently. Any idea why it works but not all the time?

Comment: If you have a reproducible example of a bug you can report it to the package maintainer.